# passing ng-repeat item into a outter function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Having this escenario:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div ng-model='item.name' contenteditable>Default text</>
</div>
<button ng-click="addItem()">Add Item</button>
<button ng-click="manageItem(item)">Manage item</button>
```

So, what I need is, when I click Manage Item, I need to pass the current item I have the cursor placed at the moment (is editable) so I can modify my current item.name model.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `item` only exists in the child scope within `ng-repeat`. Why don't you put the button inside ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div ng-model='item.name' ng-focus="setItem(item)" contenteditable>Default text</>
</div>
```

inside controller:

```
$scope.edit = {};
$scope.setItem() = function(item){
    $scope.edit = item;
};
```

then inside `manageItem` use `$scope.edit`instead of the param